# Tool for sql query across multiple and different databases?

Tags: sql

Does anyone know a simple SQL tool which allows me to do querys and joins across mutliple and different databases (oracle, sybase, syqlserver, ...) using JDBC/ODBC

Something like you yould do with Visual Foxpro

```
orclConn = SQLCONNECT({oracle database connection string})
SQLEXECUTE(orclConn, [SELECT ... FROM oracle_table], 'oracle_cursor')
fbConn = SQLCONNECT({firebird database connection string})
SQLEXECUTE(fblConn, [SELECT ... FROM firebird_table], 'firebird_cursor')
SELECT ... FROM oracle_cursor, firebird_cursor ON {join condition}
```

I need to do checks accross diffrent databases like "is one customer key available in another system"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [tutorial on how to query multiple databases](http://www.unityjdbc.com/doc/multiple/multiplequery.html) and the different techniques and options.  If the databases are not on the same server, take a look at [UnityJDBC](http://www.unityjdbc.com).  It allows you to write a SQL query that can join and compare data from different databases (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, Microsoft, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the oracle product "Database Gateway for ODBC (DG4ODBC)". I've used it to connect to access databases transparently from Oracle - I can't remember if I did joins or not, I mainly used it for ETL.

The other alternative I use a lot is Groovy - http://groovy.codehaus.org/ - it uses jdbc and is incredibly easy to use, again though no joins.

hth

Comment: with db links you could do joins but sadly the Database Gateway is serverisde ... I only have a restricted user ... so I can not do such things at serverside and our infrastructure admins are not willing to :-) and a local installed oracle database is some kind of overkill isn't it? in groovy you can not join, you could load the record setd into arrays and join them ... but its some kind of an overkill too ...

Comment: @christian - it depends how often you need to do this - I used dg4odbc for a migration project. Likewise in groovy you can do the join yourself - select from oracle_table where key = var_1 and select from firebird_table where key = var_1 and see if the answer you get is the same - it depends on your application requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There is a freeware tool to exec on multiple Databases using ODBC drivers :
http://www.geniusconnect.com/articles/DeveloperProducts/2/4/9/